# Modify/align itemize bullet position

Tags: beamer, itemize, alignment

I'd like to modify the position of bullet points in this slide so that the bullet points are aligned (i don't need pefect precision, just to reduce the misalignment.
Thanks for the help

Also if anybody knows how to align the two words "Misura" at the beginning of the lines

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,handout]{beamer} %rimuovere handout per la versione lunga
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Stato Sperimentale}%{Asimmetria di $\mathcal{CP}$ per $\Lambda_b^0$}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.7\linewidth}
                \hspace{0.09cm}Misura di CDF\footnotemark (3 fb${}^{-1}$ a 1.96 TeV):%Measurements of Direct C P-Violating Asymmetries in Charmless Decays of Bottom Baryons,
            \begin{itemize}
                \item $\mathcal{A}_\mathcal{CP}^{p K}=(-10\pm 8 \pm 4)\%$
                \item $\mathcal{A}_\mathcal{CP}^{p \pi}= (-6 \pm 7 \pm 3)\%$
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.3\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{}
                \centering
                $\mathcal{A_{CP}}=\frac{|A|^2-|\bar{A}|^2}{|A|^2+|\bar{A}|^2}$
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \footnotetext[1]{CDF Coll., Physical Review Letters, 113 (2014)}
    \pause
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{1\linewidth}
            Misura più precisa ad opera della collaborazione LHCb (Run 1)\footnotemark\\ (Campione di dati corrispondente a 1 fb${}^{-1}$ a 7 TeV e 2 fb${}^{-1}$ a 8 TeV): %Search for CP violation in $\Lambda_b^0\to pK^-$ and $\Lambda_b^0\to p\pi^-$ decays,
            \begin{itemize}
                \item $\mathcal{A}_\mathcal{CP}^{p K}=(-2.0\pm 1.3 \pm 1.9)\%$
                \item $\mathcal{A}_\mathcal{CP}^{p \pi}= (-3.5 \pm 1.7 \pm 2.0)\%$
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}\footnotetext[2]{LHCb Collaboration,  Physics Letters B, 787 (2018)}\pause
    \begin{block}{}
        \centering  Nessuna evidenza di violazione di $\mathcal{CP}$
    \end{block}\pause
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    Nuovo campione (Run 2 LHCb, 6 fb${}^{-1}$ a 13 TeV)\\
    Aumento dimensione del campione + Ottimizzazione selezione\\ $\to$ riduzione incertezza statistica
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: highlight of things i'd like to be aligned]

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `siunitx` package to get proper spacing between your numbers and units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, columns have different margins than normal text. You can avoid this by using the `onlytextwidth` option (if you want to use this for your whole presentation, you can also use this as class option)

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,handout]{beamer} %rimuovere handout per la versione lunga
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Stato Sperimentale}%{Asimmetria di $\mathcal{CP}$ per $\Lambda_b^0$}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{0.7\linewidth}
                Misura di CDF\footnotemark (3 fb${}^{-1}$ a 1.96 TeV):%Measurements of Direct C P-Violating Asymmetries in Charmless Decays of Bottom Baryons,
            \begin{itemize}
                \item $\mathcal{A}_\mathcal{CP}^{p K}=(-10\pm 8 \pm 4)\%$
                \item $\mathcal{A}_\mathcal{CP}^{p \pi}= (-6 \pm 7 \pm 3)\%$
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.3\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{}
                \centering
                $\mathcal{A_{CP}}=\frac{|A|^2-|\bar{A}|^2}{|A|^2+|\bar{A}|^2}$
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \footnotetext[1]{CDF Coll., Physical Review Letters, 113 (2014)}
    \pause
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{1\linewidth}
            Misura più precisa ad opera della collaborazione LHCb (Run 1)\footnotemark\\ (Campione di dati corrispondente a 1 fb${}^{-1}$ a 7 TeV e 2 fb${}^{-1}$ a 8 TeV): %Search for CP violation in $\Lambda_b^0\to pK^-$ and $\Lambda_b^0\to p\pi^-$ decays,
            \begin{itemize}
                \item $\mathcal{A}_\mathcal{CP}^{p K}=(-2.0\pm 1.3 \pm 1.9)\%$
                \item $\mathcal{A}_\mathcal{CP}^{p \pi}= (-3.5 \pm 1.7 \pm 2.0)\%$
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}\footnotetext[2]{LHCb Collaboration,  Physics Letters B, 787 (2018)}\pause
    \begin{block}{}
        \centering  Nessuna evidenza di violazione di $\mathcal{CP}$
    \end{block}\pause
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    Nuovo campione (Run 2 LHCb, 6 fb${}^{-1}$ a 13 TeV)\\
    Aumento dimensione del campione + Ottimizzazione selezione\\ $\to$ riduzione incertezza statistica
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]